# What is a correct question?

Tags: questions, subject-auxiliary-inversion

What is a correct question to this answer?

> We have our Spanish lessons in the center.

A: Where do you have got Spanish lessons?

B: Where have you got Spanish lessons?

Notice: considering that (have got = study)

Answer (score 2):

Your premise that "have got = study" is mistaken.

*Have got* in contexts like *I've got Spanish at ten o'clock* or *I've got Spanish at the Community Center* is just an ordinary use of the collocation to mean *have* in the sense "experience".

It's understood **from context** to mean "have a class" or "have a class session", which could be paraphrased "study" to some degree; but that doesn't mean that it's equivalent to "study", which is also (and primarily) used to mean "engage in a prolonged effort to learn" and involves (or should involve) many activities besides attending classes.

What you want to ask is

> Where/when have you got Spanish (lessons)?, *or*
>
> Where/when do you have Spanish (lessons)?, *which is more likely in US speech. And in US speech if you're including "lessons" it is even more likely to be*
>
> Where/when **do you get** Spanish lessons? *if you're asking about general accessibility, or*
>
> Where/do you get **your** Spanish lessons *if you're asking about your hearer's personal experience and schedule.*

Answer (score 2):

The phenomenon of changing the order of the verb and subject for questions and negation is known as "subject–verb inversion". Typically, only auxiliary verbs are inverted to denote a question, so if the verb isn't auxiliary, the dummy verb "do" is added. "have", when used to create the perfect aspect, is auxiliary, but it's not being used in that sense here, so it is not an auxiliary verb here, and thus  generally "do" is used. Inverting "have" in this context is somewhat archaic and occurs more in BrE than AmE. Additionally, using "have got" rather than just "have" is also more BrE than AmE. Standard AmE would be "Where do you have Spanish lessons?" Even in BrE, "have got" is usually used more in the sense of "possess" than in the sense of "undergo".

Comment: +1 for accurately setting out the syntactic principle I was fumbling to convey in my comment.

Comment: About my question: the answer of the person referred to "possess" in "your Spanish lessons". Perhaps configure of my two questions for asking about the 'the place' wasn't correct. but, What's wrong? if I used this sentence "Where do you have got Spanish lessons?"

Answer (score 0):

In the phrase "you have got", the word "have" acts as an auxiliary verb, so the question form is "have you got" and the negative form is "you haven't got". (And the negative question forms are "haven't you got" and "have you not got".)

So the correct question form here is *B: Where have you got Spanish lessons?*